# Null pointer dereference when hooking system call with kprobe

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I've been trying to hook the connect() system-call on Debian (kernel version 5.10.0-20-amd64). Though the kprobe itself succeeds, I can't retrieve the sockaddr from the pt_regs structs.

My code looks like this:

```
static struct kprobe kp = {
    .symbol_name = "__x64_sys_connect",
};

static int handler_pre(struct kprobe *p, struct pt_regs *regs) {
    struct sockaddr *addr = (struct sockaddr * )(regs->si);
    if (addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        printk("Hurray!");
    }
   return 0;
}

static int __init my_hook_init(void) {
    kp.pre_handler = handler_pre;
    int ret = register_kprobe(&kp);
    if(ret<0) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Kprobe failed %d\n", ret);
        return ret;
     }
     printk(KERN_INFO "Kprobe at %p\n", kp.addr);
     return 0;
}

static void __exit my_hook_exit(void) {
    unregister_kprobe(&kp);
    printk(KERN_INFO "kprobe at %p unregistered\n", kp.addr);
}

module_init(my_hook_init);
module_exit(my_hook_exit);
```

And the error I get is this:

BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 000000000000002a

What am I doing wrong? Isn't the second argument to a system call supposed to be stored on rsi on 64-bit architectures?

Comment: I'm not familier with those system calls, but blindly dereferencing any pointer without checking for `NULL` doesn't seem to be a good idea. You do not verify `regs` and also not `addr` before you access the memory

Comment: The error persists even after checking for both regs and regs->si. I even declared and assigned a value to *addr in two separate lines, in accordance to the C90 standards, but still

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved (at least in the sense that the system no longer crushes) after replacing __x64_sys_connect with __sys_connect, and enabling the kprobe after successfully registering it.
Something like this:

```
    static struct kprobe kp = {
    .symbol_name = "__sys_connect",
    .flags = KPROBE_FLAG_DISABLED
};

static int handler_pre(struct kprobe *p, struct pt_regs *regs) {
    struct sockaddr *addr = (struct sockaddr * )(regs->si);
    if (addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        printk("Hurray!");
    }
   return 0;
}

static int __init my_hook_init(void) {
    kp.pre_handler = handler_pre;
    int ret = register_kprobe(&kp);
    if(ret<0) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Kprobe failed %d\n", ret);
        return ret;
     }
     printk(KERN_INFO "Kprobe at %p\n", kp.addr);
     enable_kprobe(&kp);
     return 0;
}

static void __exit my_hook_exit(void) {
    unregister_kprobe(&kp);
    printk(KERN_INFO "kprobe at %p unregistered\n", kp.addr);
}

module_init(my_hook_init);
module_exit(my_hook_exit);
```